# ClassDefNotFound in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, external

I've been jumping through hoops trying to include my utility jar in my project. Android documentation clearly states that all the import-via-filesystem should not be necessary (http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary) but I've tried all suggestions anyhow; putting in it a libs folder, clean the project, restarting eclipse.

Is there any way I can see how eclipse builds the project; I'd like to see that it actually tries to include my jar.

Comment: without proper code (your plugin.xml and the MANIFEST) it's difficult to help you. the error normally disappears when you set the dependencies and libs in your plugin.xml correctly.

Comment: Have you added the library to your build path?

Comment: It seems to have to do with the jar itself, other jars I can add without problems to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to solve the problem, but it seems to be caused by the Android cross compiler not being able to correctly process the generated Jar. As a work around I started copying the java files from the utility project into the Android project.

Answer (score 3):

Build and Clean is not enough, you should add your jar file by configuring the Build Path. Follow these steps:

- Right Click on your project
- => Properties
- => Java Build Path ( at left )
- => choose the tab Libraries
- => add jars
- => specify your jar file that you have added it to the lib folder.

Hope it helps and sorry for my English

Comment: done that in 10 different ways, so I'd like to see that it actually is being used.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding the jar to the build path isn't enough. You have to copy the jar to the project's folder (like to /libs).

Comment: again, tried that, the documentation (see link in original post) clearly states that is not required, but tried it anyway. Also tried doing it by import->filesystem. No go.

Comment: all I'd like to do now is see the adb statements that the eclipse pluging is executing, so I can see if it is attempting to include the library and why it may fail.